# Prove that $\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1} \ge e^{-1}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, exponential-function

$\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1} \ge e^{-1}$

I think it's true that $e^{-1} \ge \left(1 - \frac1n\right)^n$

Is that at all useful?

Thanks!

Comment: Check that $1-x \geq e^{-x/(1-x)}$ for $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n-1} \ge e^{-1}<=>e \ge (1+\frac{1}{n-1})^{n-1}$, true.

Comment: Could either of you explain further?

Siméon, how is that inequality true?

Medicu, why is the if and only if part true?

Answer (score 2):

First, we know $1+x\le e^x\,\,\,\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, if $n\neq 1$
$$1+\frac{1}{n-1}\le e^\frac{1}{n-1}$$
$$\iff \left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}\le e$$
$$\iff \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}\ge e^{-1}$$

**Note:** I just explicitely used the inequality medicu took for granted in his comment.

Comment: How does the very fact implication follow?

Comment: Sorry I meant "how does the very last implication follow"

Comment: Just add the fractions, and get the reciprocals of each side.